# Postdoc application and ignored?

Tags: postdocs

**UPDATE:** received a reply from PI wishing me a good luck on my future endeavors.

I have sent my CV and letter to a PI. The PI received and replied me "we will review and get back to you".
As of now, 30 days has passed and I have sent a follow-up email two days ago.
Is it normal that PI just ignore or not reply to candidate who they think doesn't fit into their lab?

I'm kinda confused with the last reply and not sure application review process usually take this long. (The lab is quite big with 15-20 postdocs).

Comment: Is there a typical application for the position? We need more information than what you've given to answer effectively, but keep in mind that it might be off cycle (summer), so faculty might be a bit out of pocket when it comes to decision making.

Comment: Thank you for  your comment! I don't think there is a typical application for the position. But I'm not sure whether I'm just off-candidate list or the faculty is too busy to inform me about the application review result (usually reject or interview offer).

Comment: It makes a lot of difference whether there was a position advertised, or not. Was it? Or not?

Comment: @paulgarrett the position was advertised on a website and the position ad is now gone. I guess the faculty have enough size of candidate pool.

Comment: If the lab is that big the position might well have received 100+ applicants. With four, roughly, chosen for interview, the other 96+ will not hear anything back usually.

Answer (score 3):

Well… was there an ad for a postdoc position?

If no, then exactly what do you expect?  That this person reply to you on your schedule?

If yes, then presumably there was a deadline, and there may have been multiple candidates (possibly 10s if the group is as large as your suggest).    The process of hiring takes time so it’s likely you will get an update if you are selected for the position or for an interview.

… and it is not uncommon for people not to reply to unsolicited emails or CVs.  Some do reply, others don’t.  Why would you expect they necessarily would if this is unsolicited?

Comment: Yes there was ad for the postdoc position.

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty normal and nothing personal against you. Well-known groups get tons of applications. It might happen that they need more time and it might also happen that they forget to answer to some of the applicants. You should just continue applying to other positions as well and not think about it too much.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It really helps me not thinking about it too much :)